# How to monitor, when innerText is added within a class

Tags: javascript

I am trying to monitor some elements within the following class  `table-responsive` within this class `table table-striped table-condensed`
for example one of the following elements is `<td style="opacity: 0.25; width: 14.29%; border-top: 0px;"><a href="/game/1680737" style="color: rgb(255, 90, 95);">1.69x</a></td>`
How do I track when one of these elements is changed and call to a function when an element is changed which runs the following script.
I've tried `Array.Observe` as well as `Proxy` I am not familiar with either so my unsuccessful attempts may be due to my own dumbfoundness. 
`Before Examples : 1.17x    4.28x   1.14x   3.13x   1.42x   3.7x    3.49x`

```js
function Calltofunction()
      {
        var stuff2 = document.getElementsByClassName("table-responsive");
     var Before= stuff2[0].innerText;
        var stuff3 = stuff2[0].getElementsByTagName("td") //I can get new elements with this but how do I detect a change?
     var res = Before.slice(0, 5);
     Before = res;
     Before = Before.replace('x',' ');
        Before.trim()
      }
```

Comment: Can you please provide the HTML code, too.

Comment: @slevy1 It's already in the question `<td style="opacity: 0.25; width: 14.29%; border-top: 0px;"><a href="/game/1680737" style="color: rgb(255, 90, 95);">1.69x</a></td>`

Comment: How does the content change in the first place?

Comment: @zer00ne New information is being outputted every so often, but not at the same time. There is a new Tag being created each time <td></td> I can get this tag but I need to detect a change.

Comment: @Javascript do you have any control of what is in `<td>` like another tag within `<td>`? Do you know what function/method is used to change the `<td>`?

Comment: @zer00ne No I don't know what function/method is used to change `<td>`

Comment: Yes I can control whats in `<td>`